# Hover effect gets stuck in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I have an input number that, when hovering, changes the border color to orange, but gets stuck and it doesn't go back to its original color. This only happens in Firefox.

Is it a bug in Firefox? Is it because it is an input tag? I couldn't find anything similar.

This is the css if it helps (`cell` and `box` are classes in the input and `calendar-inventory` is the big container):

```
.calendar-inventory .cell.box:hover, .calendar-inventory input.box:hover {
  border-color: #f68a0a;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: share your html as well..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I am not allowed to share the html. I know it is complicated without, but it is working in chrome and ie, so I was hopping that maybe was a bug from firefox or a common error on inputs

Comment: You don't have to provide confidential content but if you can't reproduce it here we can't help.

Comment: Without the html we can't guess what is wrong. Can't you make a fake html code example to reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I change the css for a script adding a class when an input gets hover.
     $( "input" ).hover( function() { $( this ).addClass( "hovered" ); }, function() { $( this ).removeClass( "hovered" ); } );